# How can i extract words from a string before colon and excluding \n from them in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to extract from a string the words that are before colon (:) but without the \n characters

I have the following string:

```
enx002: connected to Wired connection 2
docker0: connected to docker0
virbr0: connected to virbr0
tun0: connected to tun0
```

I would like to extract the words before :

I used a regular expression:

```py
pattern = '[^:-].*?:\s*'
xx = re.findall(pattern, stringfromabove)
```

I do get a list of strings as expected just that they are taking also : at the end as well \n
example:
xx[3] will be '\ntun0: '

What I want is to be just 'tun0'

thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'^[^:-][^:]*', stringfromabove, re.M)
re.findall(r'^([^:\n-][^:\n]*):', stringfromabove, re.M) # This will make sure there is a `:` on the line and `\n` will make sure the match does not span multiple lines
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vi3Tmk/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^:-]` - any char but `:` and `-`
- `[^:]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `:`
- `^([^:\n-][^:\n]*):` - captures a sequence of any char but `:`, `-` and a newline followed with  any 0 or more chars other than `:` and newline at the start of a line, and also matches a `:` right after (that is not part of the group and is thus not returned by `re.findall`).

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sHV0Rm):

```py
import re
rx = r"^[^:-][^:]*"
text = "enx002: connected to Wired connection 2\ndocker0: connected to docker0\nvirbr0: connected to virbr0\ntun0: connected to tun0"
print( re.findall(rx, text, re.M) )
# => ['enx002', 'docker0', 'virbr0', 'tun0']
print( re.findall(r'^([^:\n-][^:\n]*):', text, re.M) )
# => ['enx002', 'docker0', 'virbr0', 'tun0']
```

Comment: nice..., thank you, it did solve my issue :)