# Extract substring from dot untill colon with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, substring, punctuation

I have a string that resembles the following string:

```
'My substring1. My substring2: My substring3: My substring4'
```

Ideally, my aim is to extract 'My substring2' from this string with Python regex. However, I would also be pleased with a result that resembles '. My substring2:'

So far, I am able to extract

```
'. My substring2: My substring3:'
```

with

```
"\.\s.*:"
```

Alternatively, I have been able to extract - by using Wiktor Stribiżew's solution that deals with a somewhat similar problem posted in [How can i extract words from a string before colon and excluding \n from them in python using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078435/how-can-i-extract-words-from-a-string-before-colon-and-excluding-n-from-them-in) -

```
'My substring1. My substring2'
```

specifically with

```
r'^[^:-][^:]*'
```

However, I have been unable, after many hours of searching and trying (I am quite new to regex), to combine the two results into a single effective regex expression that will extract 'My substring2' out of my aforementioned string.

I would be eternally greatfull if someone could help me find to correct regex expression to extract 'My substring2'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non-greedy regex (with `?`):

```py
import re

s = "My substring1. My substring2: My substring3: My substring4"

print(re.search(r"\.\s*(.*?):", s).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
My substring2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I am obtaining '. My substring2:', it is nonetheless the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might for example exclude matching the dot as well, and use a capture group matching any char except the `:`

```
^[^:-][^:.]*\.\s*([^:]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:-]` The first char can not be either `:` or `-`
- `[^:.]*` Optionally match any char except `:` or `.`
- `\.\s*` Match a dot and optional whitespace chars
- `([^:]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vt2qkh/1)

Or a bit shorted if there can not be `:` `.` and `-` before matching the dot:

```
^[^:.-]+\.\s*([^:]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCrTbV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2Dz5RM)

For example

```
import re

s = "My substring1. My substring2: My substring3: My substring4"
pattern = r"[^:-][^:.]*\.\s*([^:]+)"
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
My substring2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Weirdly enough, the results between the regex demo and the extraction of desired substring from my 'real' string are inconsistent; I am getting 'My substring1'. The first thing that comes mind is that my 'real' string and my 'mock' are disparate. However, 'My substring1' is clearly separated by '. ' from 'My substring2' in both my 'real' string and my 'mock' string - that should be clear characteristic to border the two substrings, should it not? No idea why I am seeing this inconsistency.
Btw, I am using Python 3.9.

Comment: @Derk I have added some example code.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following regex, code is written and tested in Python3. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKvOGV/1) for used regex.

```py
import re
s = "My substring1. My substring2: My substring3: My substring4"
re.findall(r'^.*?\.\s([^:]+)(?:(?::\s[^:]*)+)$',s)
['My substring2']
```

***OR:*** use following regex with only 1 capturing group, little tweak to above regex, here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/luQLh0/1) for below regex.

```
^.*?\.\s([^:]+)(?::\s[^:]*)+$
```

***Explanation:*** Using `re` module of Python3 here, where I am using `re.findall` function of it. Then creating variable named `s` which has value as: `'My substring1. My substring2: My substring3: My substring4'` and used regex is: `^.*?\.\s([^:]+)(?:(?::\s[^:]*)+)$`

***Explanation of regex:*** Following is the detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^.*?\.\s      ##Matching from starting of value of variable using lazy match till literal dot followed by space.
([^:]+)       ##Creating one and only capturing group which has everything just before : here.
(?:           ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
  (?:         ##Starting 2nd non-capturing group here.
     :\s[^:]* ##Matching colon followed by space just before next occurrence of colon here.
  )+          ##Closing 2nd non-capturing group and matching its 1 or more occurrences in variable.
)$            ##Closing first non-capturing group here at end of value.
```

Comment: You can omit the outer non capture group `^.*?\.\s([^:]+)(?::\s[^:]*)+$`